# NavigationLink passing a post, receiving it as a model creates issues of 'let' being a constant

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to pass a single post data to be populated in a form if a user wishes to update them, like so:

ContentView.swift

```
List(vm.posts, id:\._id) { post in
                        NavigationLink(destination: FormView(post: post)){
                            VStack{
                                Text(post.title)
                                    
                                Text(post.content)
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
```

This is the model:

```
struct Post: Codable {
    let _id: String?
    let title: String
    let content: String
    }
```

FormView.swift

```
struct FormView: View {
    @State var post: Post

    var body: some View{
        Text(post.content)
        TextField("Title", text: $post.title)
        TextField("Content", text: $post.content)
        Button("Submit"){
            print("submit")
        }
    }
}
```

the error:

> Blockquote Cannot assign to property: 'title' is a 'let' constant

what am I doing wrong? this isn't the correct logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding to a 'let' constant. It's a constant, so it can't change. A binding implies that something can be received (get) and changed (set). Did you try with 'var' instead of 'let'?

Comment: So you suggest to change the model Post to have all as vars instead of lets? I'm new to swift/ui so excuse my ignorance, but all of the tutorials I have seen, build the models as lets in all constants inside of them.

Comment: You could also do a Custom Binding, but I don't see a point in doing that. If you want to change something in the model, i.e. you want to save what's input in the TextField, then the property should be 'var' not 'let'. You can't update a constant